# Two columns same height - Bootstrap - CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I'm creating a product box with two columns near each other, left one have the product image and right one product description.

The main problem is, I'm trying to make the product description the same height as the image, but after few tries I didn't get close to solve it, because it needs to be **responsive**. I tried a lot of solutions but still stuck, the closest one was using media queries and apply height to the `.product-det` but seems like it's not the good way.

I have create a [Bootply as a demo](http://www.bootply.com/Ym5PWOXm9u).

The blue border must reach the bottom of the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12 padding-15 margin-b-15 border-default padding-t-0 padding-b-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 nopadding">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 border-l-default">
                            <div class="row">   <a href="#" title="" class=""><h4 class="col-xs-10 margin-t-15 text-ellipsis">Article pokeball superpotion lighting boltubertext pokemon pikachu</h4></a>

                                <div
                                class="col-xs-2 padding-t-15">  <span class="pointer pull-right">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                                </span>

                            </div>
                            <div class="product-det col-xs-12 line-h-35">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">ITEMID</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="qnt" type="text">  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>

                                            </button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="pull-right">3.203 €</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="">Right content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.padding-15 {
  padding: 15px;
}
.padding-t-15 {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.margin-b-15 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.border-default{
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.padding-t-0 {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.padding-b-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
}
.line-h-35 {
  line-height: 35px;
}
.border-l-default {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: is the image should be square? i mean not 250px x 250px, i mean the height should be following your bootstrap col width?

Comment: here is solution without flex and js: http://www.bootply.com/kYphIQyinm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

Html:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <!--The div columns you want them to be same height should be here-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
  Row with equal height columns
*/
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
 }
```

Comment: ah nice you were a minute faster than me xD

Comment: Holy s-, are you a wizard? It works, can I have a little of more information and if it will work at all browsers? :)

Comment: Thanks man :) . Yeah display: flex works fine in different browsers...check this  https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

you can try javascript to do this. because bootstrap col is changing width overtime when you change your devices. I like it, it typeless and you can put the class in your image wrap and your product descript wrap like so:

```js
var st = $('.squarethis').width();
$('.squarethis').css({'height':st+'px'});
$('.sameheight').css({'height':st+'px'});
```

```css
.wrapper{
background:#ccc;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex-direction:row;}

.prodImage{
width:30%;
background:red;}

.prodDesc{
width:70%;
background:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="prodImage squarethis"></div>
<div class="prodDesc sameheight"></div>
</div>
```

it will apply on your bootstrap. try to input this.

let me explain what happened:

1. `$('.squarethis').css({'height':st+'px});` it will make your image always square, and it don't care what devices you using.
2. `$('.sameheight').css({'height':st+'px'});` and this thing will make your next bootstrap col following the height of your previous col.

don't forget to input a class in your image wrapper and description wrapper

Comment: @Troyer since bootstrap col change the width every time, you can't guess what height in that device right now. Unfortunately i don't know that css has that technology to understand "what height it is".  your welcome man.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to look at [bootstrap v4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) which comes with awesome features, like [flexbox grid](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/).

It does just what you need - example:

```css
#foo{
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 300px;
}

#bar{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="bar">bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/595tesq9/)

Answer (score 1):

You can tune this cell (product description) using plain css. Just a little modify class `.border-l-default`:

```
.border-l-default {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

**[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kYphIQyinm)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the text ellipsis like that, it is a bit rude because i didn't use bootstrap classes, but it works fine to me:

```
.text-ellipsis {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   margin-bottom: 71px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it will not work because small devices have smaller height :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set min-height in different mediaquery

```
.border-l-default {
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    min-height: 135px;
```

Comment: Sorry It must be responsive solution, with fixed height it will destroy responsiveness :)

Comment: set min-height in all media query